# Problema "List index out of range"

Tags: python, lista

Em um código Python eu possuo várias condições que filtram os meus dados, e esses dados estão ligados a um contador de posição `i`.

Porém dentro de uma dessas condições específicas eu preciso gravar a posição do dado naquele ponto para utilizá-lo depois. Para isso eu tentei criar uma lista e quando essa condição fosse satisfeita, a posição seria inserida na lista.

Eu li um pouco sobre e entendi que o problema é que eu estou tentando iterar a lista enquanto reduzo o valor de `i`, porém não sei como posso contornar essa situação.

Como o código é um pouco extenso eu vou colocar apenas algumas partes para exemplificar:

```
redline = []
.
.
.
for i in range(n-2):    
.
.
.
if dvaz[i-1] <= 0 and dvaz[i+2] >= dvaz[i]  and dvaz[i] >= 0.11:
            dvaz[i] = dvaz[i]
            redline.append(i)
.
.
.
fou.write('{};{};{};{}\n'.format(i, vaz[i], dvaz[i], redline[-1:])
```

`redline` é a lista criada para acrescentar os valores de `i`, e no caso só é acrecentado na condição acima. Porém quando chega no arquivo de saída, o valor até fica correto, porem ele fica dentro de `[]`, e eu precisaria que apenas o valor fosse escrito.

Um exemplo de como o arquivo de saída é escrito dessa forma:

```
1; 1; 1; [1]
```

Caso eu retire o `:`, surge o erro `list index out of range`.

Comment: O que é n? Não seria melhor fazer `len(lista)-2` dentro do range?

Comment: Isso foi feito anteriormente, mas de uma outra maneira, o n é ````len(vaz)````, e ````dvaz = diff(vaz)````

Comment: Um jeito fácil de atingir o que tu queres, talvez não o mais "pythonico", seria substrituir `redline[-1:]` por `str(redline[-1:]).replace('[','').replace(']','')`

Comment: Funcionou pra mim, obrigado! Você poderia colocar isso como uma resposta, para que eu possa marcar como respondida? Obrigado

Comment: `redline[-1:]` retorna uma lista contendo o último elemento de `redline`... se você quer apenas o último elemento, sem ser uma lista, use `redline[-1]`... Isso só vai funcionar se a lista não for vazia... A lógica do seu programa precisa ser pensada para o caso da lista ser vazia... Não precisa de gambiarra

Answer (score 1):

Antes você tem que entender o que está acontecendo. Suponha que eu tenha essa lista:

```
redline = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Ela tem 6 elementos: os números de zero a 5. Se eu quero pegar um elemento específico, por exemplo, o que está na posição 3, eu faço:

```
print(redline[3])
```

O código acima imprime `3`, já que é o elemento da posição 3 (lembrando que a primeira posição é `0`). De forma geral, ao usar `lista[indice]`, é retornado o valor que está na posição `indice`.

Mas o Python também permite que se use a [sintaxe de `slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para obter "sub-listas" (ou "pedaços da lista"). Por exemplo:

```
print(redline[2:4]) # [2, 3]
print(redline[2:]) # [2, 3, 4, 5]
print(redline[:4]) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

No caso, `[2:4]` significa que vou pegar os elementos do índice 2 e 3 (o valor inicial `2` é incluso, o valor final `4` **não** é incluso). Por isso o resultado é a lista `[2, 3]`.

Mas os valores podem ser omitidos. Se eu omitir o final, ele vai até o fim da lista, por isso `[2:]` pega desde o elemento na posição 2 até o fim. Já `[:4]` pega desde a primeira posição até o índice 3 (lembre-se, o valor final não é incluso).

Outro detalhe é que o Python também permite índices negativos, e a diferença é que eles começam a contar a partir do final da lista. Sendo assim, `redline[-1]` pega o último elemento da lista (no caso, é o número 5), `redline[-2]` pega o penúltimo, e assim por diante.

E se usarmos números negativos em um `slice`, o funcionamento é o mesmo. No caso, `redline[-1:]` significa que o valor inicial é o último elemento, e como o valor final foi omitido, ele vai até o final da lista. Ou seja, isso retorna uma lista contendo apenas o último elemento.

---

Outra diferença é que, se você tenta acessar um índice que não existe, a lista dá erro. Mas se usar esse índice em um `slice`, não:

```
redline = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
print(redline[7:]) # retorna uma lista vazia
print(redline[7]) # IndexError
```

A lista tem 6 elementos, então os índices válidos estão entre zero e 5. Ao fazer `redline[7:]`, o `slice` tenta pegar tudo da posição 7 até o final da lista. Como a posição 7 não existe, o resultado é uma lista vazia. Mas se tentarmos acessar o índice diretamente (ou seja, `redline[7]`, sem usar `slice`), ele dá um `IndexError: list index out of range`.

No seu caso, `redline[-1]` daria `IndexError` se a lista estiver vazia (pois como ela não tem nenhum elemento, não tem como acessar o último - e nem qualquer outro).

Por fim, quando você imprime uma lista, ela é mostrada com os delimitadores `[` e `]`, e os elementos dentro deles separados por vírgula. No seu caso, como a lista só tem um elemento (somente o último elemento), é mostrada como `[1]`.

---

Dito isso, uma maneira de resolver seu problema seria simplesmente obter o último elemento, ou "nada" se a lista estiver vazia:

```
if redline:
    valor = redline[-1]
else:
    valor = ''
```

O `if redline` é uma maneira de verificar se a lista não está vazia, já que [uma lista vazia é considerada um valor "falso"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth). Então se a lista não for vazia, pega o último elemento. Se a lista for vazia, use uma string vazia (**ou qualquer outro valor que você quiser**).

Outra maneira de escrever o `if` acima é:

```
valor = redline[-1] if redline else ''
```

Não use nenhuma solução que envolva transformar a lista em string e depois remover os colchetes, pois não faz sentido. Mesmo que "funcione" (ou seja, "mostre o que você quer"), não é o ideal, basicamente por dois motivos:

- semântica: você quer um elemento da lista, ou uma outra lista contendo um elemento? Pelo que entendi, você só quer o último elemento da lista, então a maneira correta de obtê-lo é `redline[-1]`. Ponto. Fim. Só isso, nada mais. Ok, um `if` para ver se a lista está vazia é recomendado, caso esta situação seja possível de ocorrer (e pelo que vimos, é).
- muito trabalho desnecessário: foi sugerido criar uma string a partir da lista retornada por `redline[-1:]`, e depois fazer substituições nesta string para remover os colchetes. Só porque "funciona", não quer dizer que seja a melhor maneira de fazê-lo. Não tem nenhum motivo para dar toda essa volta só para obter um valor que você pode obter mais facilmente passando simplesmente um índice.

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413468/112052) (que foi apagada) dizia que usar regex é a forma mais performática de tratar as strings. Bom, de cara eu já adianto que não é, mas em todo caso vamos fazer um teste rápido.

```
import timeit, re

# cria uma lista com os números de 0 a 199
redline = list(range(200))

def regex(redline):
    re.sub('[]/[]', "", str(redline[-1:]))

def replace(redline):
    str(redline[-1:]).replace('[','').replace(']','')

def indice(redline):
    str(redline[-1]) if redline else ''

n = 1000000
r = 5
print(timeit.repeat('regex(redline)', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.repeat('replace(redline)', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.repeat('indice(redline)', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
```

Eu usei o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) para medir o tempo de execução de cada uma das opções. Basicamente, usei a regex [sugerida na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413468/112052), o `replace` [sugerido nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412897/problema-list-index-out-of-range#comment805561_412897) e o `if/else` sugerido acima (eu até transformo o elemento em string, para deixar a comparação mais "justa", mas isso não seria necessário, já que ao imprimir o valor ele seria convertido para string).

Lembrando que os resultados podem variar bastante, pois dependem de *hardware*, de outros processos que estavam rodando no mesmo instante, etc. Dito isso, eu uso o [método `repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat), para rodar cada uma das funções 1 milhão de vezes, e faço isso 5 vezes. O resultado é uma lista contendo os 5 tempos, para cada função. Na minha máquina, obtive o seguinte:

```
[2.0180632999999997, 2.1049371000000003, 2.0531832999999997, 1.9851327000000003, 2.0050208000000005]
[1.0190392999999993, 1.0544192, 0.9397298999999997, 1.1806303000000007, 0.9278553999999986]
[0.3631664000000008, 0.36723610000000306, 0.35816770000000275, 0.40702209999999894, 0.36287220000000175]
```

Veja que a regex demora cerca de 2 segundos, enquanto o `replace` demora cerca de 1 segundo. Já o `if/else` demora cerca de 0,3 segundos. Rodei várias vezes na minha máquina, em outra máquina, no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/EmbarrassedKnowledgeableClimate#main.py) e no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/5Oj0Vd%5D) (neste último eu tive que diminuir a quantidade para não estourar o tempo permitido), e os resultados foram similares: regex sempre demora mais que o `replace`, que sempre demora mais que `if/else`, e a diferença relativa entre as soluções é similar em todos os casos. Mas sinceramente, isso já era esperado.

O `slice` tem que criar outra lista. Depois, `str` cria uma string a partir dessa lista, e [cada `replace` cria outra string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Com regex é pior porque a própria expressão regular tem que ser [compilada](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) (e convertida para uma estrutura interna), para só depois começar a fazer as substituições (sendo que a busca feita pela regex usa outras estruturas internas para obter e guardar os *matches*, e no final o [método `sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) também retorna outra string). Ou seja, além de fazer mais coisas e demorar mais para isso, ainda gasta mais memória. Dizer que isso é mais performático é uma afirmação completamente equivocada. Dizer que é "a forma correta" também é um equívoco, pois o "correto" depende de cada caso. [E regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Bom, fiz outro teste compilando a regex fora da função:

```
reg = re.compile('[]/[]')
def regex(redline):
    reg.sub("", str(redline[-1:]))
```

Isso melhora um pouco os tempos (na minha máquina, cai para cerca de 1,2 segundos), mas ainda sim é mais lento que as outras opções.

Obviamente, para programas pequenos manipulando poucos dados, a diferença de desempenho entre as 3 soluções será insignificante. Mas ainda resta a questão da semântica, de deixar o código mais claro e correto, e de facilitar o entendimento e manutenção do código. Se alguém ler `redline[-1]` (supondo que a pessoa conheça Python), estará bem claro que aquele trecho de código pega o último elemento (se tiver um `if/else`, fica claro que estou usando um valor diferente caso a lista seja vazia). Agora se tiver uma regex, pode ficar mais confuso ("*Por que converteram a lista para string e depois fizeram `replace`? Só pra pegar o último elemento, ou tem outra coisa que não entendi?*"). Ou seja, no seu caso específico, como só quer pegar o último elemento da lista, não invente. Não use `slice`, não converta para string, não faça `replace`, por que você não precisa disso para o que pretende fazer.

---

<sup>*Nem vou entrar no mérito que a regex sugerida na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413468/112052) não está totalmente certa, porque também substitui as barras (caso elas existam na string), [veja](https://ideone.com/rxS4Mm). Não faz diferença se a lista só tiver números, mas em todo caso, ela pega caracteres a mais, então não está 100% certa. A regex para remover somente colchetes seria [assim](https://ideone.com/gvux3n) (embora essa solução não considere o caso em que o próprio valor seja uma string que tenha colchetes, mas aí já estamos desviando demais da pergunta). Mas enfim, esqueça isso e não use regex, porque nesse caso não precisa.*</sup>